# How to use GitHub secrets on .env file

Tags: laravel, github, github-actions, api-key

I'm trying to access my GitHub secrets to some .env variables but without effort:

My github secret name:

```
API_KEY
```

value:

```
API_KEY_VALUE
```

on my .env:

```
API_KEY=
```

Extract from my workflow:

```
name: Laravel

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Copy .env Laravel Configuration for CI
        run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.ci', '.env');"
        env:
          CI: true
          API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was adding the env: parameters on the wrong task of my steps. I changed then to be where the tests are executed, not where the .env was created:

```
  - name: Execute tests
    run: vendor/bin/phpunit
    env:
      CI: true
      API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
```